# ICS silence on lockscreen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, customization, silent-mode

On Gingerbread, there was a nice silence slider on the lockscreen:
How do I get something like that in ICS?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use something like [widgetlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice APP full of options, among them, the slide to silence:

[Quick Launch - Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.conduit.locker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jb25kdWl0LmxvY2tlciJd)

[image: Lock Screen Print-Screen]